# How do I specify a compiler in a different directory than MinGW in a NetBeans Toolchain module

Tags: netbeans, g++, mingw, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I am attempting to make a simple ToolChain for the Borland 4.5 compiler with the Pharlap extender based on instructions at the Apache website: https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/cnd/toolchain.html

I am basing the ToolChain on MinGW so that I can use those tools for make.

I cannot get the new toolset to find the Borland compilers the way MinGW is automatically discovered.  If I use g++ as the compiler name, Netbeans finds that OK.  The issue seems to be with the directory.  I'm assuming an installation directory of C:\BC45\BIN and attempting to find BCC32.EXE in that directory.

When I run (clean, build, then run) the test installation of the netbeans module, I see my new toolchain in C/C++, but the field for the C++ compiler is always empty unless I specify a program in the c:\mingw\bin (base) directory.

I have tried variations on the following in my cpp xml file, making sure from time to time that it works just fine with g++ as the name:

```
    <cpp>
        <compiler name="bcc32.exe"/>
        <recognizer pattern=".*[\\/]bc45.*[\\/]bin[\\/]?$"/>
```

I haven't found documents beyond the Apache website.  I'm basing my guesses on what I have found in: `%appdata%\NetBeans\12.4\config\CND\ToolChain\MinGW.xml`

Comment: Borland 4.5 is 25 years old. Do you really *have* to use such an out-of-date compiler?

Answer (score 0):

The XML above was OK as far as it goes.  The example at apache.org only fills in the subclass of c++ (cpp).  When I also subclassed the c, assembler, and linker, I ended up with the fields in the C++ options automatically populating as expected.

vcc4n (https://sourceforge.net/p/vcc4n/wiki/Home/) has a good example of implementing the four important classes for those build tools, but really just continuing the example to create and fill in the additional XML as specified in layer.xml is straightforward enough.